# Unrecognized Selector Sent To Class Error

Tags: xcode

So i have a class called IAP with a .h and .m file. the .h looks like this:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <StoreKit/StoreKit.h>

@interface IAP : UIViewController <SKProductsRequestDelegate,      SKPaymentTransactionObserver, UIAlertViewDelegate>




+(void)myIAPWithItem;

@end
```

But when I call the function myIAPWithItem I get and error. I call it like this:

```
[IAP myIAPWithItem];
```

Also there is an item paramater I just took it off to test.

Answer (score 1):

Do you have an implementation in your .m file?

```
// in IAP.m

@implementation IAP

+(void)myIAPWithItem {
    // do something
}

@end
```